# How to resolve the following python Key Error

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, keyerror

I am iterating through a json file and trying to read it in python but it is showing a key error even when the key is present in the file. I am trying to iterate through the json file as follows

```
annotations1 = json.load(open('C:/Users/abhin/OneDrive/Desktop/MASK RCNN/DATA SET/train/train_json.json'))  
annotations = list(annotations1.values())  # don't need the dict keys
annotations = [a for a in annotations if a['regions']]

for a in annotations:
    polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions']] 
    print(a["regions"])
    objects = [s['region_attributes']['names'] for s in a['regions']]
    print("objects:",objects)
    
    name_dict = {"holes": 1}
    num_ids = [name_dict[a] for a in objects]
```

To recheck if the key `names` was present I print the `a["regions"]` in which you can see that the key `names` is present

```
[{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 364, 'cy': 160, 'rx': 9.541, 'ry': 15.19, 'theta': 0.748}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 529, 'cy': 168, 'rx': 10.336, 'ry': 17.991, 'theta': 0.785}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 405, 'cy': 162, 'rx': 9.541, 'ry': 17.438, 'theta': 0.753}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 619, 'cy': 174, 'rx': 11.245, 'ry': 19.878, 'theta': -2.356}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 266, 'cy': 154, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 15.19, 'theta': 0.822}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 481, 'cy': 167, 'rx': 9.541, 'ry': 17.438, 'theta': 0.753}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 678, 'cy': 178, 'rx': 12.722, 'ry': 20.365, 'theta': 0.896}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 300, 'cy': 156, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 15.19, 'theta': 0.822}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 535, 'cy': 210, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 9.574, 'theta': -2.297}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 690, 'cy': 223, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 10.697, 'theta': 0.733}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 383, 'cy': 357, 'rx': 6.21, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': 0.876}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 221, 'cy': 183, 'rx': 3.976, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': -2.498}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 300, 'cy': 190, 'rx': 5.091, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': 0.896}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 557, 'cy': 212, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 9.706, 'theta': -2.531}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 315, 'cy': 191, 'rx': 4.498, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': 0.785}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 426, 'cy': 200, 'rx': 5.622, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': -2.356}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 407, 'cy': 199, 'rx': 5.091, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': -2.246}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 717, 'cy': 226, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 9.574, 'theta': -2.297}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 425, 'cy': 352, 'rx': 4.771, 'ry': 7.951, 'theta': 0.644}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 640, 'cy': 366, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 9.574, 'theta': -2.297}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 522, 'cy': 384, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 11.301, 'theta': 0.686}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 459, 'cy': 333, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 9.706, 'theta': 0.611}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 494, 'cy': 376, 'rx': 5.566, 'ry': 8.996, 'theta': -2.356}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 334, 'cy': 311, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 9.574, 'theta': -2.297}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 612, 'cy': 362, 'rx': 8.746, 'ry': 13.68, 'theta': 0.62}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 228, 'cy': 293, 'rx': 5.622, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': 0.785}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 573, 'cy': 382, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 9.574, 'theta': -2.297}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 248, 'cy': 326, 'rx': 4.771, 'ry': 5.622, 'theta': -2.356}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 202, 'cy': 308, 'rx': 4.771, 'ry': 6.41, 'theta': -2.622}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 244, 'cy': 295, 'rx': 5.622, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': 0.785}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 304, 'cy': 328, 'rx': 4.771, 'ry': 8.452, 'theta': 0.719}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 152, 'cy': 279, 'rx': 4.771, 'ry': 7.951, 'theta': 0.644}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 358, 'cy': 348, 'rx': 4.771, 'ry': 7.951, 'theta': 0.644}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 352, 'cy': 314, 'rx': 4.771, 'ry': 8.452, 'theta': 0.719}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 266, 'cy': 333, 'rx': 5.622, 'ry': 9.541, 'theta': 0.785}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'ellipse', 'cx': 481, 'cy': 337, 'rx': 7.156, 'ry': 9.574, 'theta': -2.297}, 'region_attributes': {'names': 'holes'}}]
```

and I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "custom.py", line 198, in <module>
    train(model)
  File "custom.py", line 165, in train
    dataset_train.load_custom("C:/Users/abhin/OneDrive/Desktop/MASK RCNN/DATA SET", "train")
  File "custom.py", line 97, in load_custom
    objects = [s['region_attributes']['names'] for s in a['regions']]
  File "custom.py", line 97, in <listcomp>
    objects = [s['region_attributes']['names'] for s in a['regions']]
KeyError: 'names'
```

Comment: That's only one of the `a["regions"]`. Maybe one of the other ones in `annotations` doesn't have `names`.

Comment: @Barmar beat me to it. You're iterating through a lot of `a` objects so one of them must not have what you're looking for. Use a `try` `except` statement to filter the ones that throw `KeyError`

Comment: Sure I will check that . Could that be the only reason for the error ?

Comment: According to what you've posted, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some undefined datasets. Try to check whether all the data have all their respective classes. Or if you are using VIA, try to check the radio button on def, to set the class as default.